# How to change name of the table in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to change a name of the table in Zend Framework 2. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

In Module.php create factory

```
'Admin\Database' =>  function($serviceManager) {
$dbAdapter = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');                    
return $dbAdapter;
```

},

in the model add the next code:

```
$database = $this->sm->get('Admin\Database');
$database->query("rename table matrix_fields1 to matrix_fields", 
$database::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```